# form outcome getting used as a variable in a different file

Tags: php, forms

im working on a website where i want to take the outcome from a from and want them saved in a seperate file as php variables so i can read them out later on a diffrent part of the site. i can write some php code to a file but i writes the name of the variable and not the value.

```
<form action="change.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputlocation1" placeholder="<?php include 'data1.php'; echo $location1 ?>">
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputdate1" placeholder="<?php include 'data1.php'; echo $date1?>">
    <br>
    <textarea name="description1" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update data" class="btn btn-primary">
```

i use numbers behind the id's because i have multiple dates and locations i want to change. this is my current php code:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("data1.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$date = $_POST["inputdate1"];
$loc = $_POST["inputlocation1"];
$desc = $_POST["description1"];


fwrite($file, '<?php $loc1 = $loc' );
fwrite($file, '$date1 = $date');
fwrite($file, '$desc1 = $desc');
fwrite($file, '?>');
fclose($file);

?>
```

who can help me?

Comment: Did you get value from form?

Comment: I assume later you are going to use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). **Don't!**. Specially since this is user input. _Never trust any input_. What if someone enter a malicious code in a post field? That's a serious security issue.

Comment: Oh, and you probably forgot to add `;` to the end of the strings.

Comment: im storing the data in a separate file as php variables to later display on the site, the form is only accesible from the "admin area"

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = '$desc1 =' .  $desc;
fwrite($file, $data);
```

you  must use ***SIGLE QUOTES***

Comment: dont use single qoute when you type variable, because when u write echo "$variable"; output will be like $variable. but if u use $var="test"; echo $var output will be: test

Comment: but that what OP want to achieve. That's why i mentioned single quotes

Comment: fwrite($file, '<?php $loc1 = '.$loc );
fwrite($file, '$date1 = '.$date);
fwrite($file, '$desc1 = '.$desc);
fwrite($file, '?>');
fclose($file); so if you write variable in single quote how can you get value of that variable?? must be stored in somewhere

Comment: You can use double quotes if you scape `$`: [https://eval.in/605847](https://eval.in/605847). But using single quotes is waaay easier.

Comment: Just note that the op **is** using single quotes. The problem is probably where they want to actually display the variable (which you addressed using concatenation)

Comment: i can get this working to a certain extend, i just cannot get the post data from the form working, am i doeing something wrong in the html?